# Economic model and hazard damage in matlab

Tags: matlab

first, i want to say i am relatively new with matlab and so i am not yet very good in it.

I have the variables A,K and L and the constant alpha. Out of this, i want to model the income Y.

```
Y=A^alpha*K*L;
```

L changes at a growth rate of 0.09;

```
dL/dt= rl;
```

with L population growth; L0 (1950)=500;

I need to model this for 50 years, how can i do this in matlab? so, L has to grow every year, but with the stuff i tried i get always one output value, not 50 values (one for every year): how i have to code this in matlab?

at the moment, I have this, but it gives just the L0*(1+r) for every year

```
for i = 1:50 
    dL(i)=(1+r).*L 
end
```

and the growth rate is continuus, but in one year I have due to an event (financial crisis for example) include a population decrease of 7% in one year, for example after year 30. Thereafther, the population will grow at same rate as before. How i can do this in matlab?

thanks for answering.

Comment: This smells suspiciously like a homework assignment that you want us to solve for you.

Comment: You wont get better if we do it for you. You haven't even written any code that calculates Y!

Comment: i have written a code that calculates Y, but i haven't show it because it is not important for the problem I have

Comment: the problem is the following: this loop calculates (L(i+1) and so on right, but when i change it in (i+n) it goes wrong : all the same output values, and error relating to index exceeding matrix dimensions (however i checked them) ;  i have now this: for i = 1:50
    L(i)=(1+r).*L0
    L(i+1)=(1+r).*L(i)
    L(i+2)=(1+r).*L(i+1)
    L(i+n)=(1+r).*L(i+n)
end    ; and the only thing i want to know is how to let L(i+n) work correct

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works, i had made a mistake by defining the loop from i:50, it must be from n:50